Blazor Server App Not Displaying CSS When I Run Build on the .csproj file in Visual Studio
I have been working on a project using Blazor Server .net6. In Visual studio i normally work in the Sln file and also run build to check changes. everything always works perfectly and looks normal. we are getting close to production (I have been working on this project all by myself with no help from managers) and dont really know how to go about deployment.
I tried to run build on the .csproj as opposed to the solution file which i normally do and the css does not seem to be applied. both are in the same directory
Is this an issue. I am not sure if the sln file be used when trying to deploy or the actual .csproj
when i build the sln

when i build the .csproj

console error

this is a new project which i had just built to see if maybe i have cause the problem in development but even when i create the project and simply try to build the same issues occur.
for legal reason i cant take screenshot from my work laptop but the issues are still the same as images above
I tried to use chatgpt but it didnt help

What are you trying to built for IIS, Nginx...? In Balzor you normally publish your project. If you have several projects in the snl you need to publish the blazor code. Build -> Publish Projectname.
You do not really specify how the error occurs. Did you run it through VS and it is broken or did you just build it and tried to run it yourself from that build?

Use the Publish function (it includes doing a Build).

Hi DaGa, Yes i am trying to build it for IIS, I believe i have been stressing for no reason. I looked on tutorials and havent seen anyone try to build the .csproj and always run/build the sln and i think when i publish it it will be fine. I'll keep this thread updated as i go along

Hi Henk Holterman, I'll try that as keep you all updated.
